# Cloning a subversion project from google code using git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, google-code

There is someone's project at google code which I want to clone using git. However, nothing of these worked:

```
git clone http://some_app.googlecode.com

git clone http://some_app.googlecode.com/svn

git clone http://some_app.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

git svn -s clone http://some_app.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Can you post the actual url of the project?

Comment: Oops, I edited to remove SVN tag and then realized from the first answer that probably this is related to SVN after all, the question just doesn't have a good indication of that. I'm not sure how to undo my edit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since, based on the URL, it looks like you are trying to access a subversion repository, you cannot use git in a simple way to get to it.

Theoretically you could use [git-svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html), which you looked at in your last example, however if you don't know about it already you probably want to learn more about git and svn first.

To check the code out of an svn repository you need to use `svn`, as in:

```
svn co http://some_app.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

If you really want to use git to access the subversion repository via git, then you need to `init` the repository first. The workflow looks something like:

```
git svn clone -s http://some_app.googlecode.com/svn/
```

The `-s` switch says to use the standard layout, and so will append `trunk` to it.